# d3 I want that gridlines overflow will be hidden

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have the following d3 chart but the gridlines get out of the chart 
https://jsfiddle.net/ou28se1z/1/

```
//Define the X axis
//Define the Y axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .innerTickSize(-w)
         .outerTickSize(0)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(5);
 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(xScale)
            .orient("bottom")
             .innerTickSize(-h)
            .outerTickSize(0)
            .ticks(10);
```

i think its related to innerTickSize property

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is related to `innerTickSize` attribute. To implement gridlines within the chart, the innerTickSize should be:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
      .innerTickSize(-(h-padding*2)) 
      // within the chart height range not svg container height range
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .ticks(10);

//Define Y axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .innerTickSize(-(w - padding*7)) // within the chart width range not svg container height range
 .outerTickSize(0)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5);
```

Because in the scale setting:

```
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
   .domain([new Date(xExtents[0]), d3.time.day.offset(new     Date(xExtents[xExtents.length - 1]), 1)])
   .range([padding, w - padding * 6]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
   .domain([0, yExtents[1]])
   .range([h - padding, padding]);
```

The range for yAxis is not exactly the height of svg, thus you need to update the innerTickSize accordingly. Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fengshuo2013/18c3syds/)